# Assess whether median is significantly closer to expectation

Tags: distributions, expected-value

I have calculated the median value of certain variables. There are two sets, and two groups. In the first set, the second group is closer to the expectation and vice versa in the second set. In the figure below, the expectation is represented by the dashed line:
[image]
Is there a statistical test to assess whether in set A, group 2 is significantly closer to the expectation than group 1 and viceversa in set B?
I am assuming non normally distributed data, even if in the figure the data looks normally distributed.
Thank you

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the median or is the mean also acceptable?

Comment: Well, after doing the Shapiro-Wilk test, the data resulted slightly not normally distributed so the median would be better but, in general, also mean would do, at least for general knowledge. Tx

Answer (score 0):

The first choice for this task would be a regular t-test. Note: a t-test requires the **residuals** of the model to be normally distributed, it makes no assumptions about the data / samples. So it is perfectly fine if your data is completely non-normally distributed, as long as the residuals are OK.

If, however, this assumption does not hold, then there are various options on how to continue. For ex. Mann-Whitney U test, Kruskal Wallis test, and others, however these tests do not tell you which sample is statistically different from the others. So if you would like to get this result you could use a simple sign test, which returns medians.

Comment: I used the Mann-Whitney between group 1 and 2 and it was slightly significant in both sets. But this tells me that the two groups are different, not that group 2 is closer to the expectation (or vice versa)...

Comment: @Gigiux Yes, that's what I wrote in the anwer. If you want to get a value out then you need a different test. have you tried the t-test first to check for validity? If not, try the sign test.